# Adding a threshold to two-finger scrolling on touchpad

Tags: touchpad, multi-touch, synaptics, mouse-scroll

I accidentally trigger two-finger scrolling on my touchpad when I mean to tap-to-click. **Can I add a minimum threshold to reduce accidental scroll events?**

It causes issues when I:

- hold my finger pressed to guide the cursor and then press my thumb down at the bottom of the touchpad to click (click-then-immediate-mega-scrolljump)
- hold Control pressed and start moving the mouse cursor before releasing the key (Control+Scrolling causes page zoom in browsers)
- when moving the cursor to click a tab in GNOME Edit/Terminal/Pidgin (scrolling on the tab bar in these apps changes tab, so I select the one adjacent to the one I clicked on instead)

  `# model-information, Lenovo ThinkPad X1 Carbon (1st gen)
  Bus=0011 Vendor=0002 Product=0007 Version=01b1
  N: Name="SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad"`

Comment: This question outlines many of the reasons I always prefer a cheap USB mouse to a touchpad...

Comment: What is the output of `synclient -l`?

Answer (score 0):

As per https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SynapticsTouchpad

You can determine your input devices (not just touchpad), by using the command `xinput`

---

### From Terminal Using `xinput`

---

1. First you want to see what number your device is labelled as. Use the command `xinput list` to see all of your devices. (You could probably shorten this to a command like `xinput list |grep Synaptic -n2`, or something similar)
2. Note the id next to the Device.
3. Determine your **current** settings by doing the command `xinput --watch-props YOURDEVICEID` (YOURDEVICEID being the device id you noted in previous step)
4. You may wish to adjust sensitivity which is Synaptics Finger, but it is dependent on your actual touchpad. So you may have to tweak other ones as well. (Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to exit).
5. Once you determine what you want to change you will input it with the `xinput` with the `--set-prop` switch.

**Same Example as from top source below**

`xinput --set-prop YOURDEVICEID "Synaptics Finger" 50 80 257`

This will adjust the sensitivity of the pad in general.

---

### From Terminal using `synclient`

You can also find a configuration with `synclient`

1. Input the command `synclient -l` to view your current configuration. (You can also redirect this into an editable document if you want to manipulate it further with a command such as `synclient -l > touchpadconfig`)
2. You can set the value by doing a command like `synclient LeftEdge=130` to set left edge of the touchpad to a coordinate 130.

Unfortunately there are lot of settings which can be adjusted, and you may need to adjust them yourself. However the `man synaptics` explains each of the parameters which can be set in fairly human readable terms.

[Further Reading from Debian wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Touchpad_Synaptics#Using_xinput_to_determine_touchpad_capabilities)

[Further Reading from Arch wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/SynapticsTouchpad)

Comment: I have played around with the available options. None of them seem to solve nor reduce this problem.