# Thinkpad X1 Carbon 1st generation - third finger makes 2-finger scrolling jump

Tags: touchpad, thinkpad, multi-touch, scrolling

To clarify, two finger scroll works, but when I touch the touchpad with a third finger, sometimes it will jump to a different position on the page, and jump back once i let go of the third finger. This is very frustrating, as it's easy to accidentally touch the touchpad with a third finger when scrolling while reading.

It doesn't seem to happen all the time, but once it starts happening it keeps happening until i reboot. Can anyone help? Elsewhere I was told this is a libinput issue, but not how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

There is a question where similar problems are discussed ([Adding a threshold to two-finger scrolling on touchpad](https://askubuntu.com/questions/565705/adding-a-threshold-to-two-finger-scrolling-on-touchpad)). Also the documentation on https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SynapticsTouchpad may provide some help.